# Administration Pack Installing

Tags: windows-server-2008

I have a Microsoft Server 2008 with IIS 7 installed. I need to set it up to run PHP requests and applications, so I need to install Administration Pack and set the FastCGI within it.
Keep in mind the server CANNOT restart, it is critical to stay running.
So, the installation of the Administration Pack needs server restart?
Thanks.

Comment: Please show your own research effort before asking for help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't remember the IIS Administration Pack for IIS 7 requiring a reboot after installation.

*However*, all IIS related services (W3SVC, FTP, IISAdmin etc.) will need to restart during, and probably after installation of the admin pack.

So if your objective is to keep IIS running without interruption, then no, you'd have to call a service/maintenance window on that host in order to install the Admin Pack